# as.POSIXct behaving inconsistently

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

This might sound like a duplicate issue but I have gone through many POSIxct related bugs but did not come across this. If you still find one, I will really appreciate being pointed in that direction. as.POSIXct is behaving very awkwardly in my case. See the example below:

```
options(digits.secs = 3)
test_time <- "2017-01-26 23:00:00.010"
test_time <- as.POSIXct(test_time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
```

This returns:

```
"2017-01-26 23:00:00.00"
```

Now, I try the following option and it returns NA. I have no idea why is this behaving like that when all I need it to convert to is "2017-01-26 23:00:00.010".

```
test_time <- "2017-01-26 23:00:00.010"
test_time <- as.POSIXct(test_time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
```

Now it works fine when I do this:

```
as.POSIXlt(strptime(test_time,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
```

But for my purpose I need to have this as a POSIxct object because some libraries I am working with only take POSIXct objects. Converting POSIXlt to POSIXct again results in the same problem as before.
Is there an issue with my system settings? The date is also not one of those daylight savings times one to throw an error. Why would it work with one format and not others? Any leads/suggestions are welcome!

Running on Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: As the help page says, it's OS specific and maybe your OS doesn't support sub-second accuracy. (Mine doesn't.)

Comment: That might be true. But why does 00.020 then become 00.010?

Comment: If you post code that does that then we would be happy to read it. You should also post your OS details since this IS a Q about an aspect that is documented as being _OS-specific_.

Comment: The `%OSn` is only for formatting output. It does not work for parsing input. The extra data is there, but just rounded by default. And due to floating point math, that value can't be represented exactly: `strftime(as.POSIXct(test_time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")`

Comment: Have you tried using `test_time` (`test_time <- as.POSIXct(test_time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")`) in the function/library that you are using?

Comment: I am not sure I follow the question completely @RonakShah . I actually need to pass it to a library that only accepts POSIXct. But POSIXct is making this error

Comment: @IRTFM the code is actually the same as what I posted here. Just that it is applied to a column in a dataframe.

Comment: `test_time <- as.POSIXct(test_time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")` has class as `POSIXct`. What happens when you pass `test_time` to your function?

Comment: @RonakShah the function works fine because the library accepts POSIXct. My concern is that the time is not correct in terms of precision and I wanted to understand why that would happen. I edited my answer with OS details too.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here has to do with the maximum precision that POSIXct can handle. It is backed by a *double* under the hood, representing the number of seconds since the epoch, midnight on 1970-01-01 UTC. Fractional seconds are represented as fractional parts of that double, i.e. `63.02` represents `1970-01-01 00:01:03.02 UTC`.

```r
options(digits = 22, digits.secs = 3)

.POSIXct(63.02, tz = "UTC")
#> [1] "1970-01-01 00:01:03.02 UTC"

63.02
#> [1] 63.02000000000000312639
```

Now, when working with doubles there are limits to the precision that they can represent exactly. You can see this with the above example; typing in `63.02` in the console doesn't return exactly the same number, and instead returns something close, but with some extra bits at the end.

So now let's take a look at your example. If we start as "low level" as possible, the first thing `as.POSIXct()` does is call `strptime()`, which returns a POSIXlt object. That keeps each "field" of the date-time as a separate element (i.e. year is kept separate from month, day, second, etc). We can see that it parsed correctly and our sec field holds `0.01`.

```r
# `digits.secs` to print 3 fractional digits (has no effect on parsing)
# `digits` to print 22 fractional digits for double values
options(digits.secs = 3, digits = 22)

x <- "2017-01-26 23:00:00.010"

# looks good
lt <- strptime(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "America/New_York")
lt
#> [1] "2017-01-26 23:00:00.01 EST"

# This is a POSIXlt, which is a list holding fields like year,month,day,...
class(lt)
#> [1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"

# sure enough...
lt$sec
#> [1] 0.01000000000000000020817
```

But now convert that to POSIXct. At this point, the individual fields are collapsed into a single double, which might have precision issues.

```r
# now convert to POSIXct (i.e. a single double holding all the info)
# looks like we lost the fractional seconds?
ct <- as.POSIXct(lt)
ct
#> [1] "2017-01-26 23:00:00.00 EST"

# no, they are still there, but the precision in the `double` data type
# isn't enough to be able to represent this exactly as `1485489600.010`
unclass(ct)
#> [1] 1485489600.009999990463
#> attr(,"tzone")
#> [1] "America/New_York"
```

So the `ct` fractional part of the double value is close to `.010`, but can't represent it exactly and returns a value slightly *less* than `.010`, which gets (I presume) rounded down when the POSIXct is printed, making it look like you lost the fractional seconds.

Because these issues are so troublesome, I recommend using the low level API of the clock package (note that I wrote this package). It has support for fractional seconds up to nanoseconds without loss of precision (by using a different data structure than POSIXct).
https://clock.r-lib.org/

```r
library(clock)

x <- "2017-01-26 23:00:00.010"

nt <- naive_time_parse(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", precision = "millisecond")
nt
#> <time_point<naive><millisecond>[1]>
#> [1] "2017-01-26 23:00:00.010"

# If you need it in a time zone
as_zoned_time(nt, zone = "America/New_York")
#> <zoned_time<millisecond><America/New_York>[1]>
#> [1] "2017-01-26 23:00:00.010-05:00"
```